# Epicor BPM - Why is my method directive not working?

Tags: directive, business-process-management, erp, epicorerp

*When it comes to Epicor it's very difficult to fit a descriptive question title in the stackoverflow title box.*

I have created a Method Directive BPM in the **SalesOrder.MasterUpdate** method.

This BPM is triggered to run when a specific field is changed from any to any, for examples sake lets call this field **ttOrderDtl.Number03**.

Once triggered, the action sends an e-mail asynchronously based on a basic email template:

From: sender@web.com

To: recipient@web.com

Subject: Test email

However this does not work...

Open **Sales Order** screen > Open test order > change **OrderDtl.Number03** field > Save

And nothing happens.

I have also created a BPM to display an information window based on the same conditions criteria and this works without fail, so there are no customisation errors in the **Sales Order** screen.

This action:

> send e-mail **asynchronously** based on the **basicemail** template

Simply won't trigger.

I have tried this in multiple test environments and also restarted the app servers to cover all bases.

Why won't this trigger the email??

Any thoughts appreciated, thanks, J.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered the problem, sending the email **asynchronously** was placing the action in a backed up queue and so never actually generated.

Changing this to **synchronously** fixed the problem and the email now generates without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the asynchronous option, and I think that you probably do as it is makes things much snappier in users land,  you need to enable the Asynchronous BPM process under "System Management | Business Process Management | General Operations | Action Process

I think ours is setup to kick on the Startup Schedule and run continuously. You can set it on a schedule of your choosing.